# Force FullScreen on EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, fullscreen, mode

I am currently developing an app with Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 as my device.

My Code in the XML is:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/analysis_text"
    style="@style/icon_text"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:onClick="onBtnClicked"
/>
```

When this code executes, the full screen data entry mode (Extract Mode) is triggered automatically only in certain situations.

I would like my users to get a full data entry screen while editing text in this control, regardless of the screen or positioning of the control.

Another rephrase of this question:
How do I force full screen data entry mode for EditText boxes in my activity no matter what the content is?

Comment: have you tried  

 android:layout_width="fiil_parent"

 android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Comment: Thanks Usman Kurd, however my situation is slightly different, I have six such boxes, so I want them to expand to full screen only when the data entry happens.

Comment: Go for AutoCompleteTectView ...

Comment: Thanks Usama, I just tried that suggestion, it does not solve my original issue, data entry happens without the screen switching to a full screen mode

Comment: A bit off the line but try to open another Activity or Fragment when EditText gets Focus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this issue, not really solved, but found a valid work-around.

The workaround is that I designed a text editor (which looks similar to the fullscreen UI) and on click of each of those `EditBox`es the new UI activity is triggerred (with the `startActivityForResult()` so that once they are completed control is handed back to the calling activity) and after completion of edit the text is transferred back into the main screen.

I also ensured that those boxes which transfer the control do not take focus so that they immediately transfer control to the new UI.

This way I have been able to implement a cancel button, which now actually allows the user to go back without saving the changes he accidentally makes.

I am open to new ideas, but this has worked for me.

Code in `Activity`:

```
public void onBtnClicked(View v) {
    EditText current_text_box = (EditText) v;

    Intent intent = new Intent(ObservationActivity.this,
            TexteditorActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("start_text", current_text_box.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("start_position", current_text_box.getSelectionStart());
    startActivityForResult(intent, v.getId());
}
```

Code in XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/observation_text"
    style="@style/icon_text"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:onClick="onBtnClicked" >
</EditText>
```

To create the full screen UI I used code, you can use any like (http://android-richtexteditor.googlecode.com/)

Comment: This is a brilliant idea, I'm at the exact same situation and I've decided to follow your footsteps :) Cheers

Comment: This is really a nice workaround. Please check on my question here. And let me know if you bumped into this situation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786797/requestfocus-is-making-the-scrollview-to-jump-even-the-view-is-well-over-the-a

Comment: Facing 404. Help

Comment: @DakshAgrawal not sure if you are using Android development tools or JS based hybrids

Comment: @DakshAgrawal good app, unfortunately I cant test your app because it wants my mobile number (which I am not comfortable sharing), can you explain the issue in detail, the solution here is obviously about 5 years old

Comment: if you want skip having to override `onActivityResult` in the caller Activity, use a [viewModel as a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61918988/2445763) that both Activities use. This way you can rely on LiveData to store the EditText content

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This

```
yourEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                yourEditText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            }
        }
    });
```

Import LayoutParams of your Parent Layout. Your answer will also work well.