# How to trigger the horizontal orientation keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard, android-edittext

## Context:

I have a small `EditText` field in my Activity, and it needs to be small because there is a lot of another `View`'s on this Activity. But the content most of times are very long, and **the user have a bad experience typing long texts into a small field**.

## Question:

How i can always show the "Horizontal Keyboard" when the user click on the `EditText`, **even if the user are at Vertical Orientation(portrait)** ?

## Example:

Here is a screenshot of the "Horizontal Keyboard" that i'm talking about:

[image: horizontal keyboard]

## Important:

Setting the orientation to horizontal, is not really necessary. If this same keyboard shown on the image above can be triggered even if you are using vertical orientation, it would be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have 50 reputation points for commenting. But this link is for a question where OP is trying to disable the full screen keyboard. Perhaps if it's possible to disable, probably you are able to force enable it.

[Disabling the fullscreen editing view for soft keyboard input in landscape?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4726646/1582714)

EDIT:

So, searching a little more, I came to the conclusion that you can't force the keyboard to enter in fullscreen mode. Unless you make a keyboard app of your own that works only in fullscreen. But still would need the user to activate it on the settings menu.

Anyway, I found this solution by a user: [force fullscreen on edittext in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036945/force-fullscreen-on-edittext-in-android?rq=1), the answer suggests creating an Activity just for writing (an Activity with only an EditText as it's layout). And calling this Activity with the startActivityForResult method. Thus returning the text entered by the user and placing it on the respective EditText (or whatever widget you are going to use for the text).

Again, hope it helps.