# Force full screen editing view for keyboard input in landscape?

Tags: android

I want  the input  for my `EditText` to always use full screen view. Like this:

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/11857803/16781399/ef56cfee-482f-11e6-93ae-ae844b11933d.png

At least when it's in landscape mode. How can I accomplish this?

**EDIT**

There is a solution in a similar post that suggests to create a new activity and make it look like it went full screen...a little cumbersome; would be better to just force it since the functionality is already native

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force FullScreen on EditText in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036945/force-fullscreen-on-edittext-in-android)

Comment: The solution in that post is to create a new activity and make it look like it went full screen...a little cumbersome; would be awesome to just force it since the functionality is already native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  Its actually up to the keyboard whether it enters extract mode or not.  There's a function on the InputMethodService they can override to define what conditions they use it in.  There is no way to override the keyboard's choice if they decide not to use it (I believe you can request they not use it, but in the end its still the keyboard's decision.