# Android Kotlin Pass data from NavController to last Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

The screen was created with NavController.
There are five pages from A to E.
When passing data from A to B, I sent it using Bundle.
But what do I do when I send data from A to E?
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
Do I have to send it in order like this?

**FYI, I don't want to use SharePreference.**

Answer (score 0):

Use **singleton** of View Model. In fragment A u will set some data and in fragment E you can just use it.

How to implement [how to use viewmodel singleton for activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039274/how-to-use-viewmodel-singleton-for-activities)